# Distinguish between odd and even powers of a in a finite field

Tags: finite-fields

In a finite field $\text{GF}(2^n)$ with characteristic 2, is there a relatively simple way to distinguish between the odd and even powers of the primitive element $a$?

In other words, given an element $y$ such that $y=a^k$, how can I find out if $k$ is odd or even without resorting to a lookup table?

Regards,

-Dimitri

Comment: Your exponent $k$ is, essentially, defined modulo the odd integer $2^n-1$; so, you can find both even and odd values of $k$ with $y=a^k$. You can, of course, ask about the parity of the *smallest* $k$ with this property, but this question does not look particularly natural to me.

Comment: Moreover, there are many primitive elements $a$, and their odd/even powers will change as $a$ changes.

Comment: Both comments are correct and I appreciate the answers. Seva, yes I meant the smallest k with this property. Greg, I meant for a given primitive $a$.

Comment: If there were an easy way of distinguishing odd/even in the "smallest $k$" sense, then that would immediately lead to a solution of the base $a$ discrete logarithm in $GF(2^n)$. Therefore I doubt that nothing much can be said in general.